# How do I edit in Magento <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW" /> for individual pages

Tags: magento, metatag

I am struggling to find in Magento a way to edit the `<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">` for individual pages.

Does anybody know how to? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do so on a per module basis, via layout xml files.

For example, should you need to set robots to NOINDEX, FOLLOW, on the Popular Search Term page:

1. Locate the layout (module) for this particular page -> e.g. app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/catalogsearch.xml
2. Locate your page: `<catalogsearch_term_popular translate="label">`
3. Add the following lines along with other references:

   ```
   <reference name="head">
       <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
   </reference>
   ```

You could do the same for any other module (checkout, sendfriendemail etc...) for which you would need to change the default robots value.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your setup... we've got a module that you can select NOINDEX/INDEX,FOLLOW/NOFOLLOW on the admin section of each page.

Have a look at http://yoast.com/articles/magento-seo/ point 3.1.

Comment: Thanks Vince, good article, my problem is that I can't find the pages that I want to edit in the backend. I am a fresher with Magento and probably looking in the wrong place.                                                              I am trying to edit things like
/catalog/category
/tag/
/checkout/
/contacts/
/customer/
/review/
/product/
/whishlist/                                                          Could you please tell me more about your module?                                                                 Thank you

Comment: Ups had to read again the article, understood yoast metarobots module and will consider installing it. Thanks I really appreciate it